# Task causes a segfault when it deletes one of the iterated objects

Tags: c++, iterator, openmp

The next code crashes since one of the OpenMP tasks deletes one of the elements pointed by `it`. How could I fix this problem? The code has to be implemented using OpenMP tasks.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp single nowait
   {
      for (std::list<Class*>::iterator it = myClass.begin(); it != myClass.end();) {
         if ((*it)->getNumber() == 0) {
            #pragma omp critical
            it = myClass.erase(it);
         }
         else {
            #pragma omp task firstprivate(it)
            { 
               bool result = (*it)->function(t);
               if ( result ) {
                  #pragma omp critical
                  it = myClass.erase(it);
               }
            }
         }
         ++it;
      }
   }
   #pragma omp taskwait
}
```

Comment: With `#pragma omp single` is this even threading related?

Comment: I answered. Two links: [Select Isn't Broken](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html) and [Nobody Writes Test Cases Anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)

Comment: It is `local_it=it++;`, not `local_it=++it;` ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erasing nodes from `std::list` using multiple threads is very tricky. You have to not only erase nodes in critical zone, but also take care of the iterator used for list traversal.

When you are using one thread to do `++it` and other threads to do the `list.erase(it)`, you may find that the node pointed by `it` could be already erased before `++it` is done, and doing `++` on an iterator pointing to a non-exist node will result in an undefined behavior.

One possible solution is that you ensure `++it` is done before the node is erased/changed, and as indicated by @sehe, you should not `++it` after an `erase`.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
   #pragma omp single nowait
   {
      for (std::list<Class*>::iterator it = myClass.begin(); it != myClass.end();) {
         if ((*it)->getNumber() == 0) {
            #pragma omp critical
            it = myClass.erase(it);
         }
         else {
            std::list<Class*>::iterator local_it=it++;
            #pragma omp task firstprivate(local_it)
            { 
               bool result = (*local_it)->function(t);
               if ( result ) {
                  #pragma omp critical
                  myClass.erase(local_it);
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
   #pragma omp taskwait
}
```

Comment: "an iterator pointed to a non-exist node will definitely crash the program" is misleading. The painful thing is: it won't _definitely_. Chances are, it won't and simply sells your cat to your dentist.

Comment: @sehe: Adding that one to my collection of UB symptoms

Comment: @sehe sorry, non-native speaker here. I mean "doing `++` on an iterator pointing to a non-exist node" will crash the program. Can we say that?

Comment: No. Because the behaviour is undefined. In all likelihood it won't (directly) cause the program to crash (because that would be a very nice guarantee to have)

Comment: @Eric Undefined behaviour is **undefined**.

Comment: The iterator can be modified by the task, while the iterator has not come to the end.

Comment: @smc what is that mean? Of course your second version code in the question does not work. It actually exact the same as your first version.

Comment: @Eric, I think your version and my second one are quite similar. The "it" can be deleted by a task while the main thread increments the iterator. The tasks are run as soon as they are created by the main thread.

Comment: @smc unfortunately they are totally different. My version ensure 2 things: 1) `++` is done before launching a new task; and 2) no `++` if `(*it)->getNumber() == 0`. But your version don't. These 2 key points make sure the code run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You simply shouldn't be incrementing `it++` after `erase`, because you might run past the end iterator (if you erased the last element).

A simple demonstration (watch how the `assert` succeeds!):

```
#include <list>
#include <cassert>

struct Class { int getNumber() const { return 0; } };

int main()
{
    std::list<Class*> l { new Class() };
    for(auto it = l.begin(); it != l.end();)
    {
        if((*it)->getNumber() == 0)
            it = l.erase(it);

        assert(it == l.end());

        it++; // OOOOOPS!
    }
}
```

Comment: `it` is thread local variable in the task as defined by `firstprivate`, so `++it` won't change anything outside the task.

Comment: @Eric Yeah, I'm not up to speed with task-based openmp. Removed the 'fix' idea to prevent confusion